# Spring Singleton bean management

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

There is scenario where we have 50 browsers opened accessing the application , if there is a singleton scoped(meaning one bean per container), then how the singleton bean is shared among all the instance of threads

or  if one object is shared to only one browser(client) then all other client will be idle waiting which is bad design

Could some body suggest answer

Answer (score 1):

For stateless beans, having a single instance ("singleton") is fine:

```
@Component
public class MyManager {

    public void doStuff();
}
```

Any number of clients (browsers) can call `doStuff()` without impacting each other as long as `doStuff()` doesn't manage state.

For stateful beans that manage user state, you can use [session scoped beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-session):

```
@SessionScope
@Component
public class UserPreferences {
    private String username;

    public setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    //...
}
```

The `UserPreferences` bean is instantiated once per HTTP session. Hence every client (browser) gets its own object.

In both cases one client (browser) does not have to wait until processing has finished for other clients.

Comment: thanks for the reply , if one object exist how call all the clients access that object simultaneously ?

Comment: Define a `@Controller` (which is a singleton) with a field `@Autowired private MyManager myManager`, call `@RequestMapping` methods from any number of clients. Since the controller is a singleton, it reads from the same myManager object, for whatever client made the call.